# jQuery out of sync

Tags: jquery, css

I have a slideshow and another function to change the style of a four boxes using the code below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#fp-slides')
    .cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed:  '2500', 
        timeout:  '3500', 
    });
    var $elements = $('#fp-menu h2 a'); 

var total_elements = $elements.length;
var element_with_class = 0;
var handler = function () {
  $elements.eq(element_with_class).removeClass('over');
  element_with_class += 1;
  if ( element_with_class === total_elements )
  {
      element_with_class = 0;
  }
  $elements.eq(element_with_class).addClass('over'); 
};
window.setTimeout( function() { 
    handler(), 
    window.setInterval(handler, 6000); 
}, 4000);


});
```

The first change on the second function needs to be quicker then set to 6000 milliseconds... which works fine, but the top slideshow which uses the jQuery.cycle function goes out of sync after a few loops of the transitions. Is there a way to keep these in sync?

Comment: can anyone tell me what are the possible values for "fx" please...!!!???

Comment: All the Effects are at: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var slides = jQuery('#fp-slides')
    slides.cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed:  '2500', 
        timeout:  '3500', 
    }).cycle('pause');

    var $elements = $('#fp-menu h2 a'); 

    var total_elements = $elements.length;
    var element_with_class = 0;
    var handler = function () {
        $elements.eq(element_with_class).removeClass('over');
        element_with_class += 1;
        if ( element_with_class === total_elements ) {
            element_with_class = 0;
        }
        $elements.eq(element_with_class).addClass('over'); 
        slides.cycle("next");
    };
    window.setTimeout( function() { 
        handler(), 
        window.setInterval(handler, 6000); 
    }, 4000);
});
```

This may not be *exactly* what you want, but basically, I've told the cycler to pause immediately, and then in your handler() function, it's telling the cycler to move to the next slide.

This way the cycler will only ever animate in time with your setInterval().  You may need to adjust this with some more setTimeouts to get the exact effect you wanted, but this ought to cure the sync issue.

Answer (score 0):

Only chance I see: Have only one Interval, which starts all of the animation

```
/* pseudo code */
function intervalFunc() {
   $('.elements1').animate( ... )
   setTimeout(function() {
       $('.elements2').animate( ... )
   }, 2000)
}
setInterval(intervalFunc, 6000)
```

this will animate `elements1` every 6 Seconds and `elements2` afterwards with a delay of 2 Seconds

Comment: @XeeMezAsHu malsup.com/jquery/cycle/browser.html